# Getting "InvalidTokenFormat, Error 400" from Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: php, android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `Firebase Cloud Messaging` for my android development with `PHP` as server side language. Right now, i'm able to :

1. Receive push notification sending using Firebase Console either both real apps and emulator.
2. Got it working when testing it out from terminal(curl)

So then, i tried sending from `apps server`(using php curl) instead of `Firebase Console`. And right now, encountered this weird message `InvalidTokenFormat, Error 400` every time i'm request the POST request. Any thought?

Here is the link for Firebase Api were made : [FirebaseApi Class](http://pastebin.com/sk72Czz8)

Feel free to ask for any inputs from meif above use case didn't clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are missing something in `php curl`! (AutorizationToken) ?!

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH you meant `Authorization: key=some keys` header?

Comment: Yes something similar could you please add your curl request ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH everything inside `FirebaseApi Class` - http://pastebin.com/sk72Czz8 file. The curl code inside `init()` method body. To make a request, i just initiated `FirebaseApi` class and call `init()` method

Comment: Make sure you are using the SERVER KEY in your PHP code, not your Android key

Comment: @jesses.co.tt yea, already used that

Comment: Please add the code you are using to make the request to the question.

Comment: @ArthurThompson already solved this issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My mistake. The url should be(without slash at the end) :

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send request to the firebase from your server with message of the notification and the token of the users then firebase will accept the request and broadcast the message to all the users (tokens that we provide) in form of a notification .

Firebase and device works on poll model, hence only firebase can send notification on your device , you can setup your poll with the device but google does not allow that because if each and every app starts to make a poll tunnel with the device , it will take up whole lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Post the raw request curl sends to the server? Normally curl does provide a printout for that, not sure about the php version.

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS does not want a JSON. if you want to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, use http_build_query($message) , or if you want to send a multipart/form-data request, give it the $message array directly.

Comment: Indeed, but in FCM case, it does need for `application/json` header along with `json` data as i choose `application/json` instead of `text`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali oh, then i *think* you're supposed to use CURLOPT_INFILE / CURLOPT_READFUNCTION , not CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS